# Does changing the system time adversely effect SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can't find anything on this with Google.  My SQL Server is on a VM and for some reason the system clock wanders from the Domain time, up to ~30 seconds.  This happens randomly 0 to 3 times per week.  I have been hounding my VM admin for months about this and he can't seem to find the cause.  He has set the server to check with the domain time every 30 minutes but this does not stop the wandering, it just fixes it faster.

Luckily the system only generates a very few transactions per hour so a 30 second time jump is not likely to cause any of the records to be out of order based on the `DATETIME` fields.

The VM stuff is out of my hands and this has been going on for months so my question is, can changing the system time cause corruption to the SQL files or some other problem I should be keeping an eye out for?

Comment: In which direction is the time "jumping?"  It could be that the time isn't really moving, but it simply slows down.  Do you have queries which rely heavily on the system time?

Comment: Only if you rely on current_timestamp/getdate()

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It seems to be drifting slowly forward, it only "jumps" when it syncs back to the domain.  This is a third party application so I don't know a lot of the internals.  There are a lot of `DATETIME` fields and the Date of when things happen is important but Time portion, in general, is not as important.  Of the queries I have looked at I would say 75-85% are have a `DATETIME` field in their predicate.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn What could happen if we did rely on "current_timestamp/getdate()"?  Its a third party app so I can't be sure how it gets the date but I it has to use one of these or related function.  Almost every table has a DateCreated and DateLastMofidifed field and there are hundreds of tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timekeeping in virtual machines is quite different from physical machines. Basically, on physical machines, the system clock works by counting processor cycles, but a virtual machine can't do it that way. [More info here](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf). So what you are seeing is normal behaviour for a VM, it's one of the fundamentals of virtualisation, and although it's annoying there is nothing you can do about it. We run plenty of SQL servers on VMs and yes, the clock jumps when it syncs, but it's never caused an issue to my knowledge.

Comment: "the system clock works by counting processor cycles" hasn't been true for several decades.  There's a clock peripheral called a Programmable Interval Timer (usually now just one of several features provided by the HPET -- high performance event timer), which runs independently of processor clocking and importantly doesn't vary with processor load the way that sleep states and boost overclocking do.  Of course, a virtual machine doesn't have its own PIT either.